# How to check different id (ref) for using one method in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, ref

I am new in Vue. In my code I gonna use a lot of same looking container and all of them should have slider page. For now when I clicking on top of container all slider-pages is coming out. I am understand,I should add id(ref) to each container. But I still cant get how to use it.  **Huge Thanks for any help or advice.**

[image]

```html
<template>
  <div @click="shotList" ref="123">
    <span>
      <div
        class="d-flex flex-row top-row justify-content-center mt-5"
        style="z-index: 111 !important"
      >
        <div class="flex-row d-flex top-size">
          <span class="col text-left" style="margin-top: -2px"
            >21:40-23:00</span
          >
          <span class="col-9 text-right" style="margin-top: -2px"
            >UFC 256 MMA</span
          >
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center"
        style="z-index: 111 !important"
      >
        <div class="flex-row d-flex bottom-size">
          <span class="col-5 bottom-size-white">Habib</span>
          <span class="col-2 bottom-size-green"
            >5%
            <p class="bottom-p">Volatility</p>
          </span>
          <span class="col-5 bottom-size-black">Connor</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
    <ListBase :title="[{ text: `3`, value: `2` }]" />
  </div>

  <div @click="shotList" ref="125">
    <span>
      <div
        class="d-flex flex-row top-row justify-content-center mt-5"
        style="z-index: 111 !important"
      >
        <div class="flex-row d-flex top-size">
          <span class="col text-left" style="margin-top: -2px"
            >21:40-23:00</span
          >
          <span class="col-9 text-right" style="margin-top: -2px"
            >UFC 256 MMA</span
          >
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center"
        style="z-index: 111 !important"
      >
        <div class="flex-row d-flex bottom-size">
          <span class="col-5 bottom-size-white">Habib</span>
          <span class="col-2 bottom-size-green"
            >5%
            <p class="bottom-p">Volatility</p>
          </span>
          <span class="col-5 bottom-size-black">Connor</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
    <ListBase :title="[{ text: `3`, value: `2` }]" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "take",
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    shotList() {
      this.show = !this.show;
      if (this.show) {
        this.$emit("openList");
      } else {
        this.$emit("closeList");
      }
    },
    spaceCheck(event) {
      let x = event.pageX;
      let y = event.pageY;
      console.log(x, y);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I guess each container already have unique id, at this point you can change your `show` with the unique id of clicked container not `boolean`. when you close the container, update `show` to `null`

Comment: I dont know where you put your `v-if` or `v-show` in your slider-page, maybe this would give us another way to get different answer